# spring3 and struts2 integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2, spring-integration

I an using struts2 and hibernate in my application. I have added ContextLoaderListener to `web.xml` .

In `ApplicationContext.xml`, I have 2 beans like this:

```
<bean id="TestImpl"
      class="Service.Impl.TestImpl">
</bean>
<bean id="testaction"
      class="Action.TestAction">
     <property name="TestIml" ref="TestImpl"/>
</bean>
```

In TestAction class I have an object and a method of this object like this:

```
private TestImpl test1;
String m = test1.testService();
```

It has get and set also.
when I run this project, when it comes to

```
String m = test1.testService()
```

nullPointerException appears.
I am not sure all configuration done correctly or something missed.
please help.

Comment: are you using the struts2-spring plugin?

Comment: I am using struts2 and spring3 libraries whithout any plugin

Comment: you have to install struts2-spring plugin

Comment: therefore you need to install Struts2-spring plugin.

Comment: you decalre the property name with a spelling mismatch.  TestIml != TestImpl

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Struts2 + Spring, Why not use their Plugin? which can be found [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html)

By using the plugin, you get tighter integration into Struts 2. This gives you the ability to inject your beans into internal framework objects, not just into your own beans.

For instance, with the plugin Struts 2 will inspect all of your actions, when it creates them to service a request, and inject them. By default Struts2-spring plugin uses autowire by name. so for example in your action class you have this code.

```
public class LoginAction extends UserAction{

    public String execute() {
        return "success";
    }

    public AuthenticateLoginService getAuthenticateLoginService() {
        return authenticateLoginService;
    }

    public void setAuthenticateLoginService(
            AuthenticateLoginService authenticateLoginService) {
        this.authenticateLoginService = authenticateLoginService;
    }

    private AuthenticateLoginService authenticateLoginService;

}
```

And In your applicationContext.xml you have this configuration.

```
<bean id="authenticateLoginService" class="services.AuthenticateLoginService"
    scope="singleton">
    <... some properties here
</bean>
```

All of the Action Classes that has a instance variable named "authenticateLoginService", spring will then inject the `authenticateLoginService` bean to all classes that has an instance variable named `authenticateLoginService` , providing that it has a setters and getters

Comment: @subodh I changed the property to test1, but NullPointerException still exist

Comment: Are you sure this is for struts2? I think it is possible without struts spring plugin

Comment: @NGS yes I am definitely sure. I am using Struts2-spring plugin in my application and that code directly came from it.

Comment: Doesn't the autowire actually hit the Javabeans property name, as expressed by the setter method name?

Answer (score 0):

your `test1` is `null` thatś why it is throwing `null pointer exception` on this `String m = test1.testService()` line.

I am not sure, but you can try this.
`property name="test1"` instead of `property name="TestIml"`

Comment: you've just made my comment as an answer.